# Why I could not create a folder named '/' using terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, mkdir

I tried creating a folder with name '/' using the mkdir command. But it returned a message saying:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/’: File exists
```

I tried quoting the the name '/', and adding escape character as \. But still it returned the same error message.
Can anyone tell me, what is the problem that I'm facing here?

Comment: Trying to create / in Linux is like trying to create C:\ in Windows.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

Comment: Nice [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297969/is-slash-part-of-the-name-of-linux-root-directory) with poetic answers on U&L :)

Answer (score 10):

`/` is a directory separator, file and directory names can't contain it. Check [Reserved characters and words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved%5Fcharacters%5Fand%5Fwords) at Wikipedia.

Using `/` alone points to the topmost directory which, as you were told, already exists.

Answer (score 6):

As the root directory (`/`) is already created when setting up the filesystem hierarchy in *nix (first time you install the system), you are getting the mentioned error saying the directory already exists.

As a side note, if you want to create a file/directory named `foo/bar`, you won't be able to because `/` is the separator used to distinguish between directories in *nix.

This comes from Unix days. According to the Unix filesystem design, a file name can contain any character except `/` and `\0` (ASCII NUL).